# Spring Data - MongoDB - Text Search und sum score in the Aggregation Pipeline with GroupOperation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following single document:

```
    @Document
    public class Comment {

        @TextIndexed(weight = 1)
        private String text;     // the actual comment itself

        @TextIndexed(weight = 5)
        private String topic;    // the topic where this comment belongs

        ....
     }
```

First of all the use case: is simple; there are many topics, and a topic may have many comments. (And yes I have been saving the topic within the comment documents redundantly for a couple of other reasons.)

What I want to achieve here is, **to have a search bar for topics on my UI, where the relevant topics are shown in a suggestion list**. The important point in this sentence was this part "**relevant** topics". So it should not just dummy search within the topics, it should also consider the comments (text attribute).

So as an example, I have these Topics and Comments:

> Topic: Donald Trump
>
> Comment1: the guy... Comment2: the president of... Comment3: here
>   another comment

Donald exists just once in this topic (so total weight is 5)

> Topic: Most powerful people
>
> Comment1: the first comment Comment2: the president Donald...
>   Comment3: Donald Trump Comment4: why Donald ..... Comment56: Donald ..

Donald does not exist in this topic itself, but it has so many comments where Donald appears (total weight is 45 i.e.), our search must also find this topic and suggest it in our suggestion list, it should even show it before the first topic since the score is way higher.

So I have already marked my document fields with some TextIndexed annotations, and some weights, in a way that I think it makes sense. So I have to make a Text-Search and I also know for sure that I have to use a groupOperation somewhere in order to just get topics as results. But I do not know how I achieve all those in a simple aggregation.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT: I now have sth. like this, but it does not work totally.

```
@TextScore
private Float score;  // a new field in Comment Document to store the score


@Service
public class CommentService {

    ...

    public Slice<TopicSuggestion> searchTopic(final String searchString) {

        TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(searchString);
        MatchOperation match = match(criteria);
        GroupOperation groupByTopicAndSumScore = group("topic").sum("score").as("score");
        SortOperation sortByScore = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "score");
        LimitOperation limit = limit(10);
        ProjectionOperation project = project()
                .andExpression("_id").as("topic")
                .andExpression("score").as("score");

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match, groupByTopicAndSumScore, sortByScore, limit, project);
        List<TopicSuggestion> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, TopicSuggestion.class).getMappedResults();

        return new SliceImpl<TopicSuggestion>(result);
    }
}
```

OutputType TopicSuggestion has just 2 fields, topic and score.

But this is my output for now (scores are 0.0, and the sort is not correct):

```
"content": [
    {
        "topic": "Donald Trump",
        "score": 0.0
    },
    {
        "topic": "Most powerful people",
        "score": 0.0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

You are needed to project text score followed by group. There is no support for adding text score through helper method in the Projection class in aggregation queries. Its only supported for regular find queries.

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(searchString);
MatchOperation match = match(criteria);
ProjectionOperation project1 = project("topic").and(aggregationOperationContext -> new Document("$meta", "textScore")).as("score");
GroupOperation groupByTopicAndSumScore = group("topic").sum("score").as("score");
SortOperation sortByScore = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "score");
LimitOperation limit = limit(10);
ProjectionOperation project2 = project("score").and("_id").as("topic");

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match, project1, groupByTopicAndSumScore, sortByScore, limit, project2);
List<TopicSuggestion> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, TopicSuggestion.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Could I also have simplified or eliminated the output type TopicSuggestion if my UI does not need to see the score, but just the ordered topic list?